# How to organise a second weekly run session?

Tags: running, training, triathlon

I've been asked about organising a run session for my Triathlon club.  The club already has a well established run session on a Tuesday night, and would like hold another on Thursday (the one relating to myself).

My question is how to differentiate this run session from the other currently running one.  The existing running session alternates between; hill reps, effort sessions, and negative split.  I want to make the session fun, and to include all members and their abilities.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the schedule of the kind of running they are alternating through and find one they do not do enough.

From your list, Tempo runs as an example.

Also try to arrange something social after like drinks, coffee, or just dinner.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea.  Probably the one thing the club doesn't do enough of is track sessions.  I like the refreshment idea as well, got me thinking of taking down a huge flask of tea for afterwards.

Comment: To be fair Tempo is not necessarily on a track.  I prefer to do it on the street, where I bike out, mark with chalk, spray chalk the K marks.  Then set out two or three such routes and rotate through them.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it social with some competitive spirit thrown in.

With a larger group of different paces, pick an out and back trail and pick a time (not distance) that everyone will turn around at, such as 25 minutes. All run at their own pace heading out for 25 minutes and all try to negative split back to the start, the faster group will run further and still get a good strong finish feel and finish about the same time as the slower group who did not run as far down the trail, but still get to finish strong.

This sort of workout allows the group to start and finish together, promoting the social aspect before and after. Allows faster runners to not feel like they have to slow down the group. It also adds a little competitive spirit, even for slower runners (can I get back before the fast guys). Finally, in a triathlon run it is good to not start too fast, start easy off the bike and build throughout the run and finish strong. Pushing for a negative split, even in a training run, forces you to run faster on the second half of the run.

Go get recovery drinks after.